# Visual Studio 2012- cannot find SDL.lib

Tags: sdl

I want to build my first SDL program in Visual Studio 2012, and I get the following error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL.lib'
```

The code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
SDL_Surface * ekran = NULL;
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    ekran = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );
    SDL_Flip( ekran );
    SDL_Delay( 2000 );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I have added library and include directories in Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories, set SubSystem to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS), also added Additional Dependences (SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib in new line).
I have no idea what is wrong. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Update the "Additional Library Directories" paths in the Linker step of the project so that it can find the library.

Comment: Thanks. Now I got another errors:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_SetVideoMode referenced in function _main. 
All the other functions return this error as well.

Comment: Have you looked up that error on MSDN for its causes?